# SQL developer keep adding white spaces within pl/sql package header on save

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

every time I save (ctrl+s) my pl/sql package for some reason sql developer add some white spaces between 'Package body' and the name of the package:

[image: before save]

[image: after save]

Can anyone tell me why this is happening or how to stop this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it actually a problem? (Other than it does not look neat and tidy?)

Comment: Can't reproduce on SQL Developer 21.2.1.204. Which version do you use?

Comment: @MT0 yes, it's a problem, some days ago I got a failed deployment using a Jenkins job because the first line of the package exceeded 4999 characters, I got a bunch of error log rows and it was not easy to determinate the root cause. I cannot access that job or modify it... or even figure out why that happened, but even if Sql Developer has no problems with that white spaces it seems some other compile tools fail there

Comment: @Littlefoot Version 17.2.0.188, thanks for your interest!

Comment: @naxo your build job is failing b/c your oracle software is more than 4 years old. Time to upgrade!

Comment: @naxo I've seen similar spacing issues with the packages in a repositories I work with, although I can't reproduce the issue myself. I *think* the issue might be related to the default keyword "EDITIONABLE". That keyword takes up the same size as the number of extra spaces. Maybe an old version of SQL Developer has some sort of trimming issue when it chooses which items to add to the "CREATE PACKAGE" command. Either way, Jeff's advice to upgrade is probably the solution. While it's hard to upgrade databases or corporate software, SQL Developer is just a bunch of files that is easy to upgrade.